# Fedora System Maintenance root password not working

Tags: passwords, fedora, root

When I was running a program on my Fedora machine, my system froze and I had to do a hard reboot. But once I rebooted, Fedora complained that the file system has errors and attempted to fix it.

Now, it gives me a screen where it prompts me to enter the root password for maintenance or press ctrl+d for reboot. But the root password which I had on my system does not work anymore. I have a ton of configurations/settings on the machine which I do not want to lose.

Am I missing something really simple ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always [boot from a rescue CD](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/s1-rescuemode-boot.html) and then blank the root password. Alternatively, [use GRUB to boot into runlevel 1](http://www.fedorafaq.org/basics/#runlevel) and you should be able to get a shell prompt without entering any password. You can then use the [`passwd`](http://www.fedorafaq.org/basics/#resetroot) command to change the password.